# my focusout event to call a function not working

Tags: jquery

I created a validateName function, it work when I call `name.validateName()`; which the name is `var name = $("#name");`

how I need to bind it together with focusout event? I want the function to execute if the input field is focusout..

I tried :

```
$(name).on('focusout', function(){
$(this).validateName();
)};
```

not working..

Comment: I think $("#name") is an element, not a selector

Comment: is there any error in the console

Comment: also what is `validateName` and how is it declared

Comment: it work when I test it like this:

name.keyup(validateName);

the function pass data through ajax and return something back

Answer (score 1):

$(name) will result to $($('#name')) in your case:

```
$(name).on('focusout', function(){
  validateName($(this).val());
)};
```

Should be like this

```
name.on('focusout', function(){
  validateName($(this).val());
)};
```

Comment: it is ok... it still gives the same object back

Comment: Object [object Object] has no method 'validateName'

Comment: @MiguelaAnthony , validatename() is the name of your function created. So you can't use it on objects unless if you extend it to have that method. Please see my update answer if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a context problem to me

From what I can understand `validateName` is a function in the wrapping object and inside the event handler `this` points to the dom element not to the outside object.

```
var self = this;
$(name).on('focusout', function(){
    self.validateName();
)};
```

Comment: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'validateName'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 var name = $("#name");

function validateName(item) {
//do your validation here.
}

name.focusout(function() {
    validateName(name);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: validateName(name.val()); <-- this work.. but why even I don't provide parameter for the function, it still work?